# gradle - deploy sub-project jar in parent-project war for eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I am using gradle. I have a war project that depends on a java project. The java sub-project, named "shared", generates a jar that is needed by the war project. This works fine for the standard gradle jettyRunWar. My problem is that the eclipse project generated by gradle does not work. The sub-project is correctly listed as a project dependency, but I get ClassNotFoundExeptions on the sub-project classes. I can't figure out why gradle isn't including the sub-project's classes folder in the war deployment.

from parent/build.gradle:

```
  compile project(path: ':shared', configuration: 'jarConfig')
```

from shared/build.gradle:

```
configurations 
{
  jarConfig
} 

artifacts
{
  jarConfig jar
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not specifically used the eclipse plugin but instead the idea plugin.

Your parent file should have the following (it probably does already) :

```
apply plugin: 'war'
dependencies {
  runtime project(':shared')
}
```

Your submodule should have:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

It shouldn't be necessary to create your own jar config configuration. Gradle already does something similar for you.

If this doesn't help, could you supply some example code of your "shared" build.gradle and some more details from your parent build.gradle.

Also it would be beneficial for you (and people helping you in here) to know how the files are build. What is in your build folder. Is the jar build? Is the jar put into the war?